# How to make tuple product of two lists in Haskell using foldr?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that converts two lists to list of tuples.

```
prod :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
prod xs ys = concat $ map (\x -> map (\y -> (x, y)) ys) xs
```

I am trying to rewrite it using foldr function.
How do i do that?

Comment: Can you show your attempts to solve the problem? What went wrong with those attempts?

Comment: Why? It's not particularly useful in real code, and it's also not particularly enlightening if you just want to learn more about `foldr`.

Comment: @Joseph I'm pretty sure it's homework

Comment: Hint: you can define `map` in terms of `foldr`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yep, its dumb homework, my problem is that can not make up a function, that has correct type for foldr

i have tried to replace map by foldr but obviously does not work.
```concat $ foldr (\x -> foldr (\y -> (x, y)) ys) xs```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh that makes sense thanks will try it right now.

Comment: It would be easier to rewrite `map` and `concat` in terms of `foldr`, and then reuse your implementation as-is (except of course using the replacement functions for those two).

Comment: @chi thanks, i kind of solved this, check out my answer below

Answer (score 3):

So after few hours and some hits from hier solved this
Hope this will be helpfull for someone else.

Basicaly this is a two nested loops implemented by foldr`s.

```
cProdFoldr :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
cProdFoldr xs ys = foldr (\x acc -> foldr (\y bcc -> (x,y):bcc) acc ys) [] xs
```